# Using ThreadPoolExecutor without Blocking

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

As a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275734/using-threading-rlock-correctly), I have a trivial script which starts a `threadpoolexecutor` to read in a `json` file. While doing that I want to it count from 1 to 9 using a `for` loop. For some reason even though I used `executor.shutdown(wait=False)` it still blocks and waits for the `read_employees` method to execute.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown):

> If wait is False then this method will return immediately and the resources associated with the executor will be freed when all pending futures are done executing

```
import concurrent.futures
import json
import time


def read_employees(read_file):
    with open(read_file) as f_obj:
        employees = json.load(f_obj)

    for emp in employees:
        print(emp)
        time.sleep(3)


def start_thread():
    filename = 'employee.json'
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.submit(read_employees, filename)
        executor.shutdown(wait=False)

def print_number():
    for num in range(1,10):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(num)


start_thread()
print_number()
```

If I were to do this:

```
def read_employees(read_file):
    with open(read_file) as f_obj:
        employees = json.load(f_obj)

    for emp in employees:
        time.sleep(5)
        print(emp)


def print_number():
    for num in range(1,10):
        print(num)


filename = 'employee.json'
empThread = threading.Thread(target=read_employees, args=(filename,))
empThread.start()

print_number()
```

It counts from 1 to 9 first and then prints out the employees, the delay is because of sleep while reading the employees. Like so:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
ams@yourcompanyname.com
bcs@yourcompanyname.com
```

How do I achieve the same output using the `threadpoolexecutor` without blocking?

Answer (score 21):

I'd recommend that you don't use a `with` statement. A `with` statement closes by calling the `__exit__` method of a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). A context manager is any class that implements an `__enter__` and `__exit__` method. So after everything is run within a `with` statement, it calls `__exit__` on the context manager that was passed in.

In this case, `ThreadPoolExecutor` is a context manager. `ThreadPoolExecutor` is a subclass of `Executor`. So by referencing [`Executor`'s class definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7eb3f8226ea7b79dae4e4e8b05730cfe0d9af7c1/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L610), we see that in its `__exit__` method it calls `self.shutdown(wait=True)`.

That call to `self.shutdown(wait=True)` is the problem. If you follow how the context manager works, since `self.shutdown(wait=False)` is the last thing in your `with` statement, `__exit__` is going to be called directly after. And that means that `self.shutdown(wait=True)` will be called. So that's what's blocking you.

You have two options to fix this. The first one is to subclass `ThreadPoolExecutor` and rewrite the `__exit__` method.

The second option is to do something like this:

```
def start_thread():
    filename = 'employee.json'
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    executor.submit(read_employees, filename)
    executor.shutdown(wait=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to this little snippet:

"You can avoid having to call this method explicitly if you use the `with` statement, which will shutdown the `Executor` (waiting as if `Executor.shutdown()` were called with `wait` set to `True`)"

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: This is why I set the `wait` to `False`, but it still outputs as if it's blocking.